# Problem: Create dynamic arrays in a class

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I'm writing a student administration program right now. I would like to do without strings and libraries to learn how to use pointers. Each student has a name, a number and several courses. I manage this data of the student in a class. Names and courses should only occupy as much space as is absolutely necessary. However, I do not know exactly how to initialize them correctly and create the constructors, setters or getters. Later, I want to manage the Student class in a class with an array of students.

I've already tried managing the char array of courses in an additional array. I did not succeed. That's why I've created a two-dimensional array now. I also came up with the idea to create extra classes for the courses and the array of courses. But that's not how I learn how to handle pointers.

student.h:

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
#include <iostream>

class Student{
private:
    int myLength_name;
    char *myName; //=new char[myLength_name];
    int myMatrikel;
    int myLength_lv;
    char *myLv;       //=new char[myLength_lv];
                        //char **myLvs[30];
    int myAnzLv;
public:
    Student();
    Student(char *name_chars, int length_name, int matrikel, int length_lv, char **lv_chars[][30]);
    char &name_chars() const { return *myName; }
    int matrikel() const { return myMatrikel; }
    int length_name() const { return myLength_name; }
    int length_lv() const { return myLength_lv; }
    char &lv_chars() const { return *myLv; }

};

#endif // STUDENT_H
```

student.cpp:

```
Student::Student() :
    myLength_name(0),
    myName(nullptr),
    myMatrikel(0),
    myLength_lv(0),
    myLv(nullptr),
    myAnzLv(0)
{}

Student::Student(char *name_chars, int length_name, int matrikel, int length_lv, char *lv_chars[][30]):
    myLength_name(length_name),
    myName(name_chars=new char[myLength_name]),
    myMatrikel(matrikel),
    myLength_lv(length_lv),
    myLv(lv_chars=new char[myLength_lv][30]),
{}
```

Can someone please help me create the class student error free? I'm really not very good with pointers and have not found helpful manuals so far.
Thanks in advance.
Eric

Comment: There isn't a single `?` character in your post. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: @MPops Oh, sorry. I completely forgot the real question. I want to rid the code of errors and I do not know how. That's why I'm looking for help here.

Comment: @EricOfficial You'll need to post those errors too. We're unsure what that means currently.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When creating a class that has a char pointer (to be used as a dynamic char array), I don't believe you will be able to use the initialization list feature of the constructor. You should first verify that it works simply by...

```
myName = new char[strlen(name_chars)+1];
strcpy(myName, name_chars);
```

This is the most basic way to do this. It's not particularly safe though, if for some reason the data doesn't come in correctly (no `\0` character in `name_chars`). But this is a start.

I would also look into `strncpy`.

To make an ARRAY of dynamic char arrays...
like ["math", "language", "writing", "history"]...

You need an `array` of dynamic char arrays.

```
char * course = new char[100]; // this is one char array of length 100.
char * * courses = new char*[10]; // this is 10 char pointers
courses[0] = new char[100]; // now, the first char pointer in courses
                            // is a dynamic array of length 100.

...
courses[9] = new char[100];
courses[10] = new char[100]; //!!!! THIS IS WRONG. Courses doesn't have 11 items in it.
                             // you can only use indexes 0-9 (10 char pointers)
```

Comment: I seriously believe that's bad advice regarding the use of idiomatic c++ programming.#

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  I agree, but I believe this assignment is forcing them to do the memory management themselves. Also it's not good to downvote an answer which directly answers the question, even if not relevant to production level code.

Answer (score 0):

@MPops
Thank you very much for your help. I hope I implemented your code right. The two files now look like this and they don't produce errors:
student.h:

```
class Student{
private:
    char *myName;
    int myMatrikel;
    char *myLv;       //=new char[myLength_lv];
    char * * myLvs = new char*[30];
    int myAnzLv;
public:
    Student();
    Student(char *name_chars, int matrikel, char *lv_chars);
    char name_chars() const { return *myName; }
    int matrikel() const { return myMatrikel; }
    char lv_chars() const { return *myLv; }

};
```

student.cpp:

`````
Student::Student() :
    myName(nullptr),
    myMatrikel(0),
    myLv(nullptr),
    myLvs(nullptr),
    myAnzLv(0)
{}

Student::Student(char *name_chars, int matrikel, char *lv_chars):
    myMatrikel(matrikel)
    {
    myName = new char[strlen(name_chars)+1];
    strcpy(myName, name_chars);
    myLv = new char[strlen(lv_chars)+1];
    strcpy(myLv, lv_chars);
    }
````
`````

Comment: You're not understanding what a pointer to a char is. Do you have any resources or tutors you can visit to help clarify these things? Read this site: http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/newdelete/50dynamalloc.html

Comment: @MPops Unfortunately, our lecturers only introduce us to the topic and want us to teach it ourselves at home. I have again informed on the topic of char pointer and made some small changes in the code. Now it shows me the warning: "in-class initialization of non-static data member is a C ++ 11 extension [WC ++ 11-extensions] char * * myLvs = new char * [30];" on. Can you help me to fix the error?

Comment: What does the error say? `in-class initialization of non-static data member...`. Are you trying to initialize this `myLvs` array inside the definition of the class? You cannot, because it is not `static`. You need to do this in the `constructor` function.